# android web view: Keyboard is not showing

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview application. On the webpage there are text fields to fill to make search. When i click on the text field to enter something it doesnt show the keyboard.

here is the java code.

http://www.a2b4.net/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like lisa points out use `webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);`

this is an example:

```
//request Focus on down.
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
//set OnTouchListener to your webView.
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can put this above this line "progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);"

Comment: Warning1- The type new View.OnTouchListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnTouchListener.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)

Comment: add this import : import android.view.MotionEvent;